# What is the best way to combine JS Objects and print them back out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to stored **2** JS objects : A, and B , in a variable called `data`.

---

## JS

```
var data = {

      "A":{"section_num":"2.2", "problem_set":"Same", "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am", "student_am":"9", "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"71", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23", "warning":"8", "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22", "success":"12", "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"},

      "B":{"section_num":"2.3", "problem_set":"Not the same", "start_time":"6/19/2015 1:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/19/2015 2:00 pm", "submit":"7", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"10", "danger_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"5", "success_list":"21,21,23,24,25"}
    
};


 var print_a = document.getElementById("print_a");
 var print_b = document.getElementById("print_b");



print_a.html(data.A.start_time);
print_b.innnerHTML = data.B.start_time;
print_a.text(data.A.start_time);
```

---

## HTML

```
<h1 id="print_a"> </h1>
<h1 id="print_b"> </h1>
```

---

I just want to print them back out.
I've tried using the dot notation to access them.
But nothing is printing out at the moment.

**0** error is in the console.

What did I do wrong ?

Any hints / suggestions ?

If you need it - [here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/4yw6cbf2/)

Comment: 1) You have malformed HTML: `<h1 id="print_a"> </div>`; 2) `print_a` variable is a DOM element, whereas `html` is a method of `jQuery` object

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `elem.textContent`

```
// example: dump entire object contents using JSON.stringify
print_a.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.A);
print_b.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.B);
```

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> below to see it work

```js
var data = {

      "A":{"section_num":"2.2", "problem_set":"Same", "start_time":"7/20/2015 10:00 am", "student_am":"9", "due_time":"7/20/2015 11:00 am", "submit":"9", "avg_score":"71", "danger":"5", "danger_list":"5,10,15,19,23", "warning":"8", "warning_list":"3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22", "success":"12", "success_list":"1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"},

      "B":{"section_num":"2.3", "problem_set":"Not the same", "start_time":"6/19/2015 1:00 pm", "student_am":"23", "due_time":"6/19/2015 2:00 pm", "submit":"7", "avg_score":"82", "danger":"10", "danger_list":"11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20", "warning":"10", "warning_list":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "success":"5", "success_list":"21,21,23,24,25"}

};


 var print_a = document.getElementById("print_a");
 var print_b = document.getElementById("print_b");

print_a.textContent = data.A.start_time;
print_b.textContent = data.B.start_time;
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="print_a"></div>
<div id="print_b"></div>
```

Comment: What I just want to print a certain object out not all of it ? Can you please show me how to do it ?

Comment: @开发人员 I've updated the code snippet. Re-run it to see that it only outputs the `start_time` field from each object now.

Comment: One gotcha with `textContent` is [IE 8 and lower support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility). Something to watch for if it matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `html()` and `text()` are present in jQuery but not native JavaScript. If I remove those from your JSFiddle, I do get output. I was easily able to detect this was the problem by opening up the Chrome dev tools while on your JSFiddle and pressing run -- there were errors logged to the console.

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw6cbf2/3/

There is not a standard way to print anonymous objects. If you have a class and are making instances of the class, you can add a `toString` method. One issue is that an object has keys and values and the keys are not ordered. You can access the keys with `Object.keys(myObject)` which will return an array. Then you can iterate over the array and print out the key and the value.

Here is an example of that:

```
var span = document.getElementById('output');

var myObject = {
    a: 10,
    b: 'cat',
    c: 'San Francisco'
};

span.innerHTML = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
    return key + ': ' + myObject[key];
}).join(', ');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4vjvc8d/

For me, on latest Google Chrome on OS X, it prints out in the order of a, b, c but that order is not guaranteed and it is important to remember that.

If you only want a printable object, you can also serialize the object to JSON with `JSON.stringify`. That will give you an output like this for the above example object:

```
'{"a":10,"b":"cat","c":"San Francisco"}'
```

Reference: [MDN on JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Your `Object.keys(...)...` code is basically doing a `JSON.stringify`. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Cymen : How's come one result is print ? just curious.

Comment: @naomik Because it is formatting the object how I want it to -- JSON.stringify will only format it to JSON of course. It gives you flexibility if you are actually outputting it for someone to read.

Comment: @Cymen I follow you. A+

Comment: @开发人员 Good catch! There was a typo on innerHTML -- it had an extra "n" in it. I fixed it and updated the link to: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw6cbf2/3/